iterator as variable data type used in collection
I'd like to use an iterator as a variable type in a collection, let's assume map.
I've tried this:
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

void f () {
  unordered_map<int,Iterator> m;
}

and also this:
template <typename M>
 unordered_map<int,M> m;

Not sure how to approach it

Iterators mostly iterate over containers. If you want one of those, declare the container type first and then use Container::iterator

but i'm declaring a map first and i need to store iterators in it later

@Minka Iterator of what type? What will they point at? Also, there is no Iterator (with an uppercase I) anywhere in the standard library

Iterators for iterating over what though? The type of the iterator depends on the type of container it refers to (or the type of stream, or ...)

Unless, you want a map that stores iterators into itself?

Please do not edit questions in a way that invalidates existing answers. You have a new question, so post it separately.

No you don't want to store iterators. Just have a look at std::vector push_back, this can invalidate iterators at any time. Iterators are views and should be kept around for as short a time as possible.

@Pepijn Kramer not helpful in my case

@Minka It is, you just don't realize it yet

@Pepijn Kramer no
also, bold statement, considering the fact, you haven't seen more of my code and you don't know what i need it for, so no, not helpful at all

There is no such type as Iterator in standard C++.   std::iterator is a templated class, and standard containers each have their own iterator types which is generally a specialisation of that template  (e.g. because iterating over a linked list like std::list works fundamentally differently than iterating over contiguous array elements).   A map can only store instances of classes, such as std::vector<int>::iterator, std::vector<double>::const_iterator, etc.   But you can't have a map of some generic iterator that is capable of iterating over any container of arbitrary types.

There isn't a singular Iterator type in C++. It is a categorisation of types, based on their behaviour.
Each container type defines a number of iterator types, e.g. std::vector<int>::iterator is different from std::vector<float>::iterator, and also different from std::list<int>::iterator, and also different from std::vector<int>::const_iterator, although in the latter case iterator is convertible to const_iterator.
As well as containers' iterator types, there are also various iterators defined in <iterator> <ranges>, and other user defined iterators. Also each pointer type is an iterator.
You have to choose which type you want in the map.
